# scroll to top not working inside absolutely positioned div

Tags: jquery, html, css

My problem is that I have a "scroll-to-top" anchor which it's not working when I give to its parent the following styles:

```
background:url('http://wallpaperlepi.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/White-Dog-And-Glasses-Wallpaper-HD.jpg');
background-position: fixed;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
position: absolute;
left:0;
top:0;
right: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
overflow: scroll;
```

If I remove position absolute and `background-position:fixed`, it works. Can anyone explain why is this happening? I really need to preserve those styles. Thanks! 
Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e4uq0jsu/2/)

Comment: when you scroll to the top of `.wrapper` it is relative to the document, not the content. try this, https://jsfiddle.net/e4uq0jsu/3/